# Need to resize images smaller and previous button is not working

Tags: jquery, arrays, image, button, resize

I have an image array and need to resize the images smaller by 35%. Here is the javascript:

```
//set up an array of comic images
var imgs = [
'http://static.wixstatic.com/media/057fb3_1e4c8262944649f989b555e3c5e9d242.jpg_1024',
'http://onlinebuilder.myregisteredsite.com/matrix/servlet/ShowAsset;jsessionid=3EE39A2568D60590C3FFD69339141C07?id=102911859',
'http://onlinebuilder.myregisteredsite.com/matrix/servlet/ShowAsset;jsessionid=3EE39A2568D60590C3FFD69339141C07?id=102911864',
'http://onlinebuilder.myregisteredsite.com/matrix/servlet/ShowAsset;jsessionid=3EE39A2568D60590C3FFD69339141C07?id=102911869',
'http://onlinebuilder.myregisteredsite.com/matrix/servlet/ShowAsset;jsessionid=3EE39A2568D60590C3FFD69339141C07?id=102911872',
'http://onlinebuilder.myregisteredsite.com/matrix/servlet/ShowAsset;jsessionid=3EE39A2568D60590C3FFD69339141C07?id=102911877'],
// initialize current to 0
current = 0;

function next() {
current++;
if (current > imgs.length) current = 0;
return imgs[current];
}

function previous() {
current--;
if (current < imgs.length) current = 0;
return imgs[current];
}

// define the first image in terms of a jquery object
var comic = $('<img/>').attr('src', imgs[0]);

// append to DOM
$('#comics').append(comic);  

$('#prev').on('click', function () {
comic.attr('src', prev());
});

$('#next').on('click', function () {
comic.attr('src', next());
});
```

On top of the jquery though is a simple html code for the buttons but I think the function prev not working is because I am doing something wrong in the jquery itself. I haven't done programming since for more than 5 years and I am pretty rusty. Any help would be awesome.

JSFiddle code:https://jsfiddle.net/sketchflygirl/4euugfsb/12/
Website code is being used at: [monroyart.net](http://sketchflygirl.wix.com/monroyart#!apophisaftermath/c60z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have defined `previous` function.

`function previous()`

but you are calling it by `prev`

`comic.attr('src', prev());`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!!!

```
<style type="text/css">
img{
height:auto;
width:550px;
}
</style>
```